# How to display images with a number inside according to a List

Tags: android, list, kotlin, textview

I want to display a certain amount of images with a number inside, which are depending on a List. The list consists of up to 4 ints, for example: (a) [4,2,2] or (b) [] or (c) [3,1] etc. The (a) example should show 3 images, with the respective numbers inside (4 and 2 and 2), the (b) example should just show the text "none" and the (c) example should show 2 images with the number 3 and 1 respectively inside.

The approach I took was to have 4 textviews with a background image (a diamond shape) and depending on the size of the list, I changed the visibility to View.VISIBLE to View.GONE and the text to the respective int.

The following screenshot shows the row layout file (as it will be viewed in a recycler view)

[image: Row Layout File]

And this screenshot shows a "real" example.

[image: "Real" example]

The code I used contains so much boilerplate and I am pretty sure someone smarter than me will have a better solution. So my questions is, how can I improve this to make it shorter/more efficient?
This is the code used in the adapter:

```
        private fun setDecoIcons(slots: List<Slot>) {
            when(slots.size) {
                0 -> {
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco2.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco3.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco4.visibility = View.GONE

                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.setBackgroundResource(0)
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.setText(R.string.textView_rowArmorListItem_deco_none)
                }
                1 -> {
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco2.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco3.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco4.visibility = View.GONE

                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ll_icon_deco)
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.text = slots[0].slotRank.toString()
                }
                2 -> {
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco3.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco4.visibility = View.GONE

                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ll_icon_deco)
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.text = slots[0].slotRank.toString()
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco2.text = slots[1].slotRank.toString()
                }
                3 -> {
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco4.visibility = View.GONE


                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ll_icon_deco)
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.text = slots[0].slotRank.toString()
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco2.text = slots[1].slotRank.toString()
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco3.text = slots[2].slotRank.toString()
                }
                4 -> {
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco4.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ll_icon_deco)
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco1.text = slots[0].slotRank.toString()
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco2.text = slots[1].slotRank.toString()
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco3.text = slots[2].slotRank.toString()
                    binding.textViewRowArmorListItemNumberOfDecorationsDeco4.text = slots[3].slotRank.toString()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use Databinding
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="scoreVM"
        type="yourPackage.ui.main.ScoreViewModel" />
</data>
```

Your image+score:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/highScoreFab"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/high_score"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:text="@={scoreVM.highCount}"
                android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_error"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
```

ViewModel:

```
var highCount = MutableLiveData<Int>()
```